# TI MSP430 JTAG Interface

Tags: msp430, jtag, texas-instruments

I am working on interfacing a JTAG interface to a MSP430BT5190. Below is a showing of how it should be connected.

Looking at the pin out of the JTAG, I see there is a TDO and TDI. When connecting this to the MSP, is it inverted such that TDO Prog -> TDI MSP and TDI Prog -> TDO MSP, as it is with a UART interface (TX->RX and RX->TX)?

MSP430BT5190 Datasheet: [Click to View](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slas703/slas703.pdf)

[image: a JTAG]
<sub>(source: [wiki.ti.com](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/images/e/e9/JTAG_4_wire_pinout.JPG))</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A great resource for designing with the BT5190 is to look at the MSP430F5438A Experimenter board. This is because the BT5190 and F5438A are equivalent for all purposes. The only difference is something which enables running the Mindtree bluetooth stack on the device (the stack won't run on another MSP430 unless you talk to them and pay).

If you look at the JTAG connections in the [Eagle schematics](http://www.ti.com/litv/zip/slac228) of that board, you see that TDI connects to TDI (pin 3 of JTAG header) and TDO connects to pin 1 of the JTAG header. So, there is no crossing of TDI and TDO.

I suggest you follow the design files closely. That serves as a sort of reference design.

By the way, if you are designing with Bluetooth and CC256x, take a look at [BTStack](http://code.google.com/p/btstack/) which is an open source stack already running on MSP430F5438A. It's open source and works nicely. You won't have to use BT5190 and pay the extra royalty.

Comment: thanks a ton. I was looking for a reference design. This really helps me out. :)

Comment: @Edwin: Sure. take a look at BTStack if it suits your purposes.